# Count function calls on Solaris

Tags: c++, profiling, solaris

I'm currently profiling a C++ application on Solaris using `collect` and `analyser`, but I only see the number of seconds spent in each functions.

How can I see the number of time each function was called ?

Is there any options I should add to the command line to enable counters? or should I use a different tool ?

Comment: It depends of your compiler. See gprof for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `collect` command doesn't work that way - it *samples* the running executable to get the call stack data it collects.

You need to [compile with `-xpg`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24457_01/html/E21991/bkana.html#bkbgg) and use `prof` or `gprof` on the output data file produced.

Something like this dtrace script would also collect function call counts:

countfuncs.d:

```
pid$target:::entry
{
    @[ probefunc ] = count();
}
```

Then run that:

```
dtrace -s countfuncs.d -c your_program ...
```

In my experience, counting the number of times a function is called doesn't really matter - it's how much *time* (CPU or wall-clock) is spent in any function that matters.  If a function takes up 90% of your execution time, that's where you spend your effort optimizing performance, whether the function was called once or billions of times.  If a function takes up 0.001% of execution time, you don't bother with it no matter how many times it gets called.

Comment: dtrace was exactly what I was looking for. I agree that most of the time the number of calls is not relevant, but sometimes it helps highlight unexpected behaviors